# Help us test the new Stack Exchange iPad app

Tags: discussion, ios-app, feedback, ipad

We've been putting the finishing touches on the Stack Exchange iOS app update for the iPad and need your help testing.

*We wish we could say more...* so we will.  The iPad update is bigger than 
bigger and rethinks the way we display the feed, user profiles and questions.

### Pretty screenshots

[image: The feed]

[image: Live Preview]

### How to Sign Up

To register for alpha testing [sign up here](https://docs.google.com/a/stackoverflow.com/forms/d/18ZDfsBm35cV72Gzf88zPaMLQwrSRPwP2__RnPb-uqTs/viewform).  If you are already an alpha 
tester for the iOS app, dig up that old email on your iPad and dive right in or sign up again if you can't find it.

After you register we will send you an e-mail with instructions on how to 
download the app on your iPad. **The invitations will be sent out in waves, so if you don’t get an invite immediately, be patient.**

### Providing Feedback

Like with the beta, crash reports will be automatically reported back to us 
using [Crashlytics](http://crashlytics.com). Bugs or feature requests should be reported here on meta and tagged [ios-app](/questions/tagged/ios-app). (For reporting purposes, the app version number can be displayed in the app by tapping the question mark near the bottom of the menu).

As always, we welcome your feedback and are committed to building the best mobile app possible for browsing the Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: Shame it doesn't work. Currently it doesn't seem to want to authorize the app, and is just rendering the standard web pages :(. I'll power cycle and see what happens.

Comment: @AndyClifton do you mean you're flat out having difficulty installing it? Are you on iOS 7.1?

Comment: @Kasra: iOS 7.1.2. I Downloaded and started the app. Logged in. The app takes you to the normal stack exchange start page and displays a message "authorizing application" in place of the usual question list. After a few minutes of waiting I got bored, hit a link, and it just shows a standard stack exchange web page. Killed the app, restarted the app, and it all works fine. Looks good!

Comment: Do you have an Android app?

Comment: @SumindaSirinathSalpitikorala you just made Kasra cry. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stackexchange.marvin&hl=en

Comment: "After you register we will send you an e-mail with instructions on how to download the app on your **iPhone**." Does that mean an iPhone is required?

Comment: Does it work with Apple Watch? I would like to flick my wrist to see a new question pop up! ;)

Comment: @abhitalks - *The ᴡᴀᴛᴄʜ

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 copy-paste problem. Only one iDevice required.

Comment: Does it make moderator functions easier to use? The mobile pages don't include them at all, and the standard web pages on iPad are incomplete.

Comment: Just curious, why does the iPad app use a different approach to the interface to the Android app on larger screen sizes? Surely the best approach on one is also the best on the other?

Comment: @BrianNickel  Is source code for SE Android, Windows, iOS app available in public domain? If yes, then where can we find out? I'm asking because Github being a private company has released the source code for its own Android app.

Comment: @AndrewLeach the app allows flagging and closing of questions and answers

Comment: But not the mod functions like the faded menu in the sidebar (which is the only way of undeleting comments)?

Comment: @AndrewLeach the apps are based on the StackExchange API v2.2 which excludes deleted items so undeletion isn't an option yet.  No diamond menu yet either.

Comment: @user568458 the Android app is currently mid-way through a tablet UI refresh too. It'll look drastically different on a tablet soon (right now it's just a blown up version of the phone's UI) -- but not exactly like the iPad app.

Comment: @NonymousNT our apps themselves aren't open source, but the vast majority of their usage is nothing but usage of our API, which is open to all and the iOS and Java implementations which the apps use are open source: https://github.com/kevin-montrose/stacman-java https://github.com/arielitovsky/stacman-objc

Comment: @David won't it be better to have a separate [meta-tag:ipad-app] for this, as those are almost two different apps?

Comment: i think that the question title seems incorrect...

Comment: I'd love to try this but I can't install on my older iOS version which is the only one I can use with my even older iPad. Shame that.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I've thought about this a bit and I think the answer is "No" -- the app is universal, and a lot of the iPad changes also change the iPhone -- if you install the newest beta on an iPhone you'll see a single page Q&A view like on an iPad.

Comment: @Kasra nice! So just add the [meta-tag:ipad] to questions about the iPad app? :)

Comment: Do you have any plans for producing SE app for Windows 8.1 environment specially for Surface Pro?

Comment: Can you go over the decision to make an app rather than just a tablet version of the website? What made you decide an app was better? I understand apps can be better in some cases. What specifically about an app for stackoverflow/stackexchange though?

Comment: @Edper nice to see someone here with a sense of humour!

Comment: @AlecTeal FB and Twitter both have one. So, does it mean they have a good sense of humor?

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi I for one am very excited for the Android app redesign (in fact that was why I clicked the link to this post; I wanted to see if there would be one). Will it be Material design?

Comment: @BrianNickel Incompatible with my Sh!tEricsson X8? Why?

Comment: Make it available for iOS devices using a version older than 7.1 - not everyone has the newest devices!

Comment: You'll get a lot more people using SO on iPads and iPhones after iOS 8 lets us install custom keyboards.

Comment: Will it have the SE "sort by interesting" view that logged-in users see on the front page of the (mobile or otherwise site)? The "feed" being different enough from that is why I'm still using the mobile site instead of the app.

Comment: I believe Jeff Atwood put it best: http://blog.codinghorror.com/app-pocalypse-now/

Comment: I just received the invitation email but i get "Unable to Download App" Stack Exchange iOS app could not be installed this time. I use 7.0.4 on a jailbreaked iPhone 5S

Comment: @Alexandros I just dropped the deployment target to 7.0.  Go ahead and try downloading again.

Comment: Its working great now! Thanks a lot @brianNickel

Comment: For very minor feature requests and bug reports, is it ok to leave a comment here, or do you want me to post them as questions anyway?

Comment: Isn't there chat option ?

Answer (score 3):

I've tried the app (the *.118 version).  I dunno what you're showing me on the home page of Stack Overflow, but it is enough to render the app unusable for me.  (I accept it might suit some other people, though I have my doubts, but it does not suit me at all.)  It is not the list of questions I'd see in a browser, and it is unusably cluttered with totally uninteresting questions.

That means I am reduced to using the app like the phone apps - quick comments to comments posted at me.  It can't be used for serious work.  I find that I cannot use the phone apps (Android and iPhone) for serious work because the keyboard is too fussy (not your fault, but a fact of smartphone life); getting to a back-quote is painful, likewise most of the programming characters.  I have reservations about the iPad app on that score, but haven't really got that far with it yet.

I was hoping that the list of questions would be tailored to the user — at least respecting the tags lists that I've set.  It doesn't; it has a pile of completely irrelevant-to-me questions on display.  (3 of 10 questions actually have tags I pay attention to, but that's a serious degradation from a 90% hit rate or thereabouts when I use a browser.)

Comment: Bingo. "Sort by interesting" from the website works fine, and it doesn't seem to be present in the app.

Answer (score 1):

I really like the fact it logs all of your accounts together ... a much better feature than online. Yes, you can log into them on separate tabs in your browser, it's just easier this way. Single login is the way to go! The side bar is very easy to navigate as well. The differences do take a bit to get used to, but it's no big deal.

Answer (score 0):

I have run into issues with the latest version of the ipad app. When trying to install the latest version it was starting (the icon changed to look like it did during the initial install) and nothing past that happened. At this point I am unable to open the app or remove it (by holding down on the icon and clicking on the red x that appears on the icon) from my ipad. Trying to re-install it does not seem to help either.

Comment: Sometimes these installs break for reasons I have yet to figure out. (I've seen it a few times since we started the alpha channel.) I think restarting your iPad will get the download process back into a state where you can try again.

Comment: @BrianNickel Thanks I will try that tonight when I get a chance.

Comment: @BrianNickel that worked thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see it mentioned above ... Why doesn't the app show us when a question is on hold?

EDIT: sorry, Version 1.1.0.125 on an iPad 3.

Comment: It does so when inside the question view itself.

Comment: @ShadowWizard ... thanks for the comment. This was pointed out to me when I actually posted this question separate (not as an answer). It bugs me that you have to go into the question in the first place to figure out that it's on hold or a duplicate, unlike when you view online, where it tells you up front. They told me this was "by design" ... cruddy design if you ask me.

Comment: Well, guess it's matter of the API not returning question state when asking for questions list.

Comment: We can actually get this from the API (a question query is a question query). It's worth looking at.

Answer (score 0):

Looks very snazzy so far. The one thing I notice is that MathJax processes beautifully in questions and answers, but *not* in comments. That is distressing. (Oh, just downloaded 1.1.0.127 today.)

Comment: It's distressing for me too, a limit of MathJax being browser based. Someday I'll wire up a JavaScript bridge to get the SVG, render the SVG to a bitmap, and embed it in the attributed string.  Right now you can open the comment menu and select an option to view the rendered math.

Answer (score 0):

I've installed a version of this app and it worked fine then it asked me to install a new one.

I installed the new one and removed the old one.

Here's my problem, I **can't open** it (anymore) **nor delete** it. I am stuck with an useless app (even after restarting my ipad).

Answer (score -5):

So .... there's no question here (that should mean downvoting!) but it really ought to be said:

On a tablet... great. Seriously guys well done, as if detecting the user agent and a web-browser wasn't enough, you actually wrote an application.

I am sure typing out answers in all but the "fluffy" SE sites will be awesome! Also much better than using a web-browser on the same device.

Math.se uses mathjax... you've lost the ability to render the nice maths that site requires! (I imagine - very unlikely you re-implemented it somehow?).

I mean seriously, what is the point! Answers in the comments!

BTW browsers have tabs, I'd hate to be finding a source and have to back out of something... Android activities handle this well, not sure about the iOS app.

Either way it'd be really annoying if (say on the Fantasy and SciFi SE) I wanted to visit youtube to reference something, or saw a few interesting questions and wanted to open more than one, I'm guessing the main view of the app will refresh each time? See sucks...

Comment: Calm down. They probably won't force you to use the app. Btw, mathjax works.

Comment: @MatthiasBauch it's more the principal, remember the old top-bar that had your name in it and a direct link to chat..... good times. Change for the sake of change is bad.

Comment: I disagree entirely with how this post was written, but the crux of the issue is absolutely true. Making a dedicated ipad app is just bad in a lot of ways, because StackExchange doesn't need it. It isn't using any features whatsoever that are only available to applications... and this design looks really easy to implement in pure HTML as well~

Comment: Sure it does. It has the feature of staying open when Safari crashes.

Comment: @TheRealBill I like that, "Why did you write this program?" -> "Oh sometimes, the usual/better/standard way of doing it would crash". I've seen people write programming languages for lesser reasons though :P

Comment: @DavidMulder A dedicated app can display out-of-app notifications when your question is updated or your answer is commented on; the Safari version can't.

Comment: @Blazemonger: If those are triggered then still a wrapper based solution would have been far more applicable. Using projects like phonegap for iOS and crosswalk for Android you are able to keep all the web's features and just add specifically the native functions you need.

Comment: @AlecTeal Who are we to judge their use of resources? You are a consumer for SE, not an owner. As Matthias said, if you don't want to use it then don't. Complaining about it without testing it doesn't contribute to the conversation.

Comment: The app is definitely tablet-friendlier than the website version. It's smoother, and most importantly, with notifications.

Comment: Just jumping in to mention that our apps are *Stack Exchange* apps, where as our sites are, well, individual sites. It's much easier to start reading cross-community content using our apps and get lost in interesting content, rather than having to make the mental decision of "Well, I'm done interacting with UX, should I go to SO?" in a browser.

Comment: [More insight on why we went for native apps vs. hybrids](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/225176/165581)

Comment: At least i expect it to load faster than a web app which will load a lot of css and javascripts.