# iPad Stack Exchange app going to working on iPhone as well?

Tags: discussion, ios-app

Would this app going to work with iPhone as well or if we have any timeline for iPhone app.

I know there are couple out there which are not official apps and they look awful...

[Help us test the new Stack Exchange iPad app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239250/help-us-test-the-new-stack-exchange-ipad-app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should already work with the iPhone. It is the Stack Exchange iOS app and has been on the market for [quite some time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228422/stack-exchange-ios-app-nearing-beta). The recent update was a modification to the app specifically aimed as iPad users, to provide a better user experience for those using the app on iPad devices.

Comment: out of context, but did anyone told you that you look just like this guy on youtube https://www.youtube.com/user/LinusTechTips