# iOS app: View hot questions across all sites?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, ios-app, hot-questions

In the iOS app, is it possible to view all hot questions across all sites? Just like the "Hot" listing on the [Stack Exchange homepage](https://stackexchange.com/).

I always find that there is constantly new interesting content here, but it seems like it doesn't exist in the app at the moment? Please let me know if I am wrong and it does indeed exist!

The feed kind of replicates this, but not quite. For some reason the posts on there are not as "hot"; as in, rather than getting 10 upvotes in one day like the items on SE's Hot page have, these ones get about 2 before appearing.

Comment: We've added this across [the iPad feed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239250/help-us-test-the-new-stack-exchange-ipad-app) and I'm planning to add the same to the iPhone sometime after our next release.

Comment: Cool. I hope the new ability to see all favorites across all sites will be in the next iPhone release too?

Answer (score 3):

Version 1.2.1 is making its way to the App Store right now with this feature.  You should see it in the next 24 hours.

Comment: Sweet thanks. That feature is the single best way to find new, engaging content across all SE sites. And that's a great thing for everyone!

Comment: I just updated. I see the hot questions. Very cool.