# Unable to update app on iOS 8.0.2

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app, ipad

I recently upgraded my iPad to iOS 8.0.2. I'm running version 1.1.0.124 of the iPad app. Whenever I open the app it tells me to update to 1.1.0.127. I tap update, and opens a certain link in Chrome. I tap install ... and nothing happens. Before upgrading to iOS 8, it would update just fine.

Currently, I have removed the app from my iPad but am unable to re-install it.

Comment: Try removing the old version first.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I removed both the iPad and iPhone versions, but it's still not working, so now I don't have any SE app available.

Comment: Well, it's not like you could use the old version (it requires to update) but yeah, this is a major issue.

Comment: 1.1.0.127 is the beta app isn't it? Try installing the "real" app from the App Store, until this bug is fixed.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I reinstalled the iPhone app from the store, but it's not the iPad one.

Comment: Oh, didn't know that. And no app for iPad in the store?

Comment: No, it's still in beta. http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239250/259693

Comment: Sorry then, thought the iOS app for iPhone also works on iPad and this one is just with extra features. :(

Comment: It works, technically, it's just made for much smaller screens.

Comment: OK, I tried pinging some devs, hope they'll have a look soon. :)

Comment: Thanks for helping out. :)

Comment: @Scimonster after you tap install, could you go to your home screen and verify whether the app is getting installed? (It looks like iOS won't send you to the homescreen automatically anymore)

Comment: @ArieLitovsky No, it's not. I checked that thoroughly.

Comment: @Scimonster could you try opening the link in Safari and check? You could either disable Chrome from the Setting App -> Stack Exchange -> Disable Chrome. Or you could copy it from the invite e-mail. Chrome is working fine here, so I'm trying to eliminate some causes.

Comment: @ArieLitovsky Not working from Safari either.

Comment: @Scimonster one last thing – try restarting your iPad. Sometimes these types of installs get kind of stuck.

Comment: @Arie I noticed some kind of internal log in iOS 8 when messing around to save battery, maybe it's logging some error with the app installation?

Comment: @ArieLitovsky Restarted, still no.

Comment: @Scimonster I've released version 1.1.0.128 – give that a try.

Comment: @ArieLitovsky Still not working. :(

Comment: @Scimonster Are you on iOS 8.0.2? It looks like it started breaking on this version.

Comment: @ArieLitovsky Yeah, i am.

Comment: Are you using WiFi when trying to install it?

Comment: @ArieLitovsky As far as i know. What else would i be using?

Comment: Well, you could be using an iPad with a 3G connection, which often could have connectivity issues.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/778/discussion-between-arie-litovsky-and-scimonster).

Comment: @ArieLitovsky You want to mark this as [status-completed]?

Comment: Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a bug with iOS 8, enterprise distribution and bundle identifiers.

SE have changed the bundle identifier [as discussed in chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/778/discussion-between-arie-litovsky-and-scimonster) in the plist to append `.ios8fix` and now it appears to work.

I've posted [an answer on Apple.SE](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/147741/68621):

> This appears to be a bug with enterprise distribution in iOS 8. If you updated to iOS 8 and had an app with the same bundle identifier installed (i.e. the same app) then you'll be unable to install the app.
>
> A workaround is to change the bundle identifier in the distribution plist. This doesn't require the actual bundle identifier of the app to change, just the distribution plist. Alternatively, you can wait until Apple fixes it.

Comment: changing the plist file and appending .ios8fix does fixes the problem but somehow it is installing older version of the app(i know older cz it is familiar) which starts crashing. and reinstalling again fixes it.