# iOS App No Longer Installing

Tags: support, bug, ios-app

When updating to 1.1.0.132 my phone showed two apps (the old app and the new app downloading. While still downloading I deleted the old version.

When the new version was done I got an error that it could not be installed. Unfortunately I no longer remember the message it gave.

Now when I attempt to re-download I get the iOS "Install"/"Cancel" dialog but when I click install nothing happens. No error, no install.

Comment: 1.1.0.132 does indeed install as a separate, new app.

Comment: Cancel that; once installed it replaces the old app entirely. As in, the installing app disappears and the icon in the old location now loads 1.1.0.132 for me. Perhaps you need to delete the app entirely, then reinstall?

Comment: @MartijnPieters, the app is gone from home screen. I can not longer access the older version - it is as if there is some ghost app sitting in the background that is preventing the new version from installing. I'm hoping I don't have to kill the phone and reinstall everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is related to the [iOS 8 bug with enterprise distribution](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/147741/68621). This caused a problem with the SE app which was raised in this meta question:

- [Unable to update app on iOS 8.0.2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240205/unable-to-update-app-on-ios-8-0-2)

SE [changed the bundle identifier](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/778/discussion-between-arie-litovsky-and-scimonster) of the distribution plist to append `.ios8fix` which is why the installation process downloads a new app. However, the bundle identifier of the actual bundle was not modified, which is why the original app is replaced.

If you delete this original app, there's no app to replace and the installation fails. Try rebooting the device, but **this seems to be a bug in iOS 8**.

Comment: Rebooting doesn't seem to work. Drat. Looks like I'm stuck with the web interface again for a while. Thank you.