# Code is not formatted when I posted answer from mobile web

Tags: discussion, mobile-web, code-formatting

Yesterday, I posted one answer from Samsung Galaxy S4, but when I opened this answer in a web browser, I saw that the posted code was not formatted.

So, is there anything (options) I have to set from the mobile-side to format this code?

Comment: You mean [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26326641/button-listener-with-fragments/26326708#26326708)? Same way you format code when posting using the website: you indent the code lines.

Comment: ya exactly. I just formatted this code Manually when i saw this answer.

Comment: Did you use the Android app or just a mobile browser? The mobile web doesn't have the editor buttons, but the only thing the editor button does is indent selected lines with 4 spaces.

Comment: I posted this answer from `Chrome Browser`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd mark code just like you would when using the desktop version of the site: by indenting the code blocks 4 spaces.

On the desktop version you can use the code button in the editor, but all that that button does is add those 4 spaces for you. In the mobile web version, you just add spaces manually.

Your [answer from yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26326641/button-listener-with-fragments/26326708#26326708) was missing those 4 spaces; you added them later on when you edited the post.

You could use the [Stack Exchange Android app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stackexchange.marvin) to post from your mobile device; it includes a post editor with a formatting toolbar. There is an [app for iOS devices too](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/stack-exchange/id871299723) ([iPad version is in beta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239250/help-us-test-the-new-stack-exchange-ipad-app))!

Comment: @MP but i already added 4 space when i posted this answer.

Comment: @MD: not according to the revision history of your post.

Comment: @MP Ok.Thax..Now i got it..

Comment: @MD: I don't do it that often, but I have posted code from my iPhone (using Mobile Chrome) and manually adding 4 spaces has always worked fine.