# Do we have any extra feature in Stack Exchange Android app than the mobile site?

Tags: discussion, questions, android-app

Today I got a Stack Overflow link in my email and when I opened it took some time loading the app (as I had set it to open stack URLs in the Stack Exchange app). The same URL if I open from Gmail in Chrome, it loads the page faster then before.

There is no doubt that the app is pretty awesome. Thumbs_up to SE for it.

Is there anything that I can do on app but not on mobile site of SE?

Comment: not really, my question is why at all its needed?

Comment: ["We decided to make native applications because we wanted to make fast applications that took full advantage of the features the OS gave them."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223942/why-did-se-develop-a-native-app-and-not-hybrid-with-webview/225176#225176)

Comment: again you are not understanding my point, I asked this question because i feel better when using the site on android chrome app but not the same with stack exchange android app. it takes more time to load than a web page. this is my point.

Comment: If it's not working for you the way you prefer, don't use it? The web interface isn't going anywhere.

Comment: +1 on Anna, if you think the mobile web version is better and that there's no benefit to the application, you can definitely continue to use the mobile web version. I'd sincerely appreciate details about why you did not like the Android app, though :)

Comment: It seems people misunderstood my question. most probably because of my bad english. I hope the updated question is clear enough.

Comment: Agree it's not a dupe, reopened.

Answer (score 4):

Basically, there are no extra features in the app, since its main goal is to provide the core features of Stack Exchange sites, only via an app which makes it more mobile friendly.

However, being an app gives it a benefit that might be considered a feature: push notifications. This means instant push notification for every inbox item you receive in Stack Exchange. In the ordinary site, you can set unread items to be emailed after several hours, but other than that, no instant notification if you're not viewing SE site at the moment.

Other than the push notifications, I can think of couple of other things that exist in the app but not in the site itself:

- Reply to comments: you can tap a comment, and a "Reply" icon appears that when tapped cause the comment author name to be automatically added with `@` in front of it. Site offers the autocomplete feature, but it's not really the same.
- Feed: not sure how exactly it works, but the Feed we have in the app does not exist in the site. It's a mix of hot network questions, with questions that might be of interest to you.

The above are not really "features", in my opinion, more like "nice to have" things.